# Calling a method defined in a module, from an overriden method in a class including that module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to call a method defined in a module, if that method has been overridden in a class.

```
Class A
 include bmodule
 def greeting
  super if some_condition_is_true
 end
end

module bmodule
  included do
    has_many :greeters
    def greeting
     puts 'hi'
    end
  end
end
```

`A.new.greeting` needs to hit bmodule's greeting if some_condition_is_true is true

I tried prepending and including the module, it did not work.  Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Now your code contains numerous problems which make it non-valid Ruby. But in general you're moving in the right direction: `super` does the job...

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the original method before overriding it:

```
Class A
  include bmodule

  alias_method :original_greeting, :greeting

  def greeting
    original_greeting if some_condition_is_true
  end
end
```

It's the example of the doc https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method

Comment: This is an alternative, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
module B
  def x
    1
  end
end

class A
  include B
  def x
    super + 1
  end
end

puts A.new.x
# => 2
```

The `included do` block with Rails *concerns* is so you can call *class methods* on the base. So I don't think you need to use it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method [Method#super_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-super_method), which provides a great deal of flexibility.

```
module M1
  def meth(arg)
    yield arg
  end
end

module M2
  def meth(arg)
    yield arg
  end
end
```

```
class C
  include M1
  include M2

  def meth(arg)
    yield arg
  end

  def test(cond, &block)
    case cond
    when :C
      meth(cond, &block)
    when :M2
      method(:meth).super_method.call(cond, &block)
    when :M1
      (method(:meth).super_method).super_method.call(cond, &block)
    end
  end      
end
```

```
C.ancestors
  #=> [C, M2, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

```
c = C.new
c.test(:C)  { |m| "meth is from #{m}" }
  #=> "meth is from C" 
c.test(:M2) { |m| "meth is from #{m}" }
  #=> "meth is from M2" 
c.test(:M1) { |m| "meth is from #{m}" }
  #=> "meth is from M1"
```

If for some reason you wanted to use `prepend` rather than `include`, `C.ancesors` would be as follows:

```
class C
  prepend M1
  prepend M2
end

C.ancestors
  #=> [M2, M1, C, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

so you would just modify `test` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, and you almost have it right. Just 1) Capitalize `Bmodule` so ruby doesn't scream at you, 2) lowercase `class` when defining A, 3) include ActiveSupport::Concern if you're using `included`, and 4) Move the greeting method out of the included block. The included block is for running things at the class level, and instance method definitions should not be inside it.

```
module Bmodule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :greeters
  end

  def greeting
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

class A
  include Bmodule
  def greeting
    super if some_condition_is_true
  end
end

A.new.greeting
```